# forcing a byte order

Tags: c, byte, endianness

```
unsigned char endian[2] = {1, 0};
short x;

x = *(short *) endian;
```

I don't understand the value held in x. If I have a little-endian system, x is 1.

But if I have a big-endian system, x is 256.

Why is the value 256 rather than 128 ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The 1 is in the zero-bit of the *most-significant* octet of a 16-bit big-endian value. Ask yourself what 2^8 is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the bytes `01 00`, in big-endian, are the value `0x0100`, which equals `1 << 8 == 2**8 == 256` (Recall there are 8 bits in a byte).

Comment: Other constraints for this solution: `CHAR_BITS == 8` and `sizeof(short) == 2`